# wpf writeablebitmap: how to set the pixel width and height

Tags: wpf, bitmap

Is there a way to set the pixel width and height of WPF bitmaps. I actually can't imagine there isn't, so I hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

With winforms I could simply use this contructor: `System.Drawing.Bitmap(Image, Int32, Int32)`.

Sorry for not being clear. With setting the size I meant scaling not cropping.

Comment: You mean after a bitmap has been created?

Comment: @Clemens: Not necessarily, I don't mind copying to a new bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [CroppedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602486.aspx) from some other (larger) bitmap, if that was your question.

---

UPDATE: In order to scale a bitmap, you may create a [TransformedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.transformedbitmap.aspx) from the original one:

```
BitmapSource originalBitmap = ...
double newWidth = ...
double newHeight = ...

var scale = new ScaleTransform(
    newWidth / originalBitmap.Width,
    newHeight / originalBitmap.Height);  

var scaledBitmap = new TransformedBitmap(originalBitmap, scale);
```

But plase be aware that this is hardly ever needed, as you will usually display the bitmap in an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) control, which already scales images very well.

Comment: I actually meant scaling, not cropping.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I'm working with image manipulation, it is necessary.